# How do I pull a Python package from private authenticated Artifactory PyPI repository?

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, pypi

I'm trying to **pip** or **pipenv** install a Python package I pushed to my organisation's private PyPI repository hosted on JFrog Artifactory.

From the [Artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PyPI+Repositories) `http://<username>:<password>@hostname...` should work. I've tried my login password and the one that gets derived from it in the **Set Me Up** tool within the **Artifact Repository Browser**.

The following commands ask for username and password but I don't want to enter them from the command line as these are going to be passed into the CI pipeline with environment variables. If I type the username and password at the prompt then it works OK.

```
$ pip search package-name --index https://user:password@organisation.jfrog.io/organisation/api/pypi/pypi/simple
User for organisation.jfrog.io: 

$ pip install --extra-index-url https://user:password@organisation.jfrog.io/organisation/api/pypi/pypi/simple package-name
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://user:password@organisation.jfrog.io/organisation/api/pypi/pypi/simple
Collecting package-name
User for organisation.jfrog.io:
```

Using `curl` to attempt HTTP authentication also does not work.

```
$ curl -i https://user:password@organisation.jfrog.io/organisation/api/pypi/pypi/simple/
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 18:03:39 GMT
Server: Artifactory/5.10.1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
X-Artifactory-Id: aolshared3a-organisation
X-Node: nginx2a.prod-euw1
Content-Length: 91
Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-a61288137a7d35f7=1; Path=/

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Authentication is required"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: For anyone still running into this, the `BCSI-CS-*` cookie is generated by BlueCoat MITM corporate proxies. As an apparent security measure, BlueCoat strips `authorization: basic ...` headers to external hosts and requires that clients resubmit the same request with the generated `BCSI-CS-*` cookie attached. For example, run this command twice: `curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -iu '<user>:<pass>' '<url>'`. One workaround with JFrog is to use the `X-JFrog-Art-API` header, but this header may not be possible with pip (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8042).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was a temporary problem with Artifactory. When I run all the code in my original question I get success - no asking for username/password, `curl` returns results, installing works. Getting in contact with someone in their support team may have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing --index with --index-url - this is what will work for the public PyPi repository as well as PyPi compliant alternatives such as [CloudRepo](https://www.cloudrepo.io) (my company's product).

If that doesn't work, try updating your version of pip and trying again with --index-url.

Comment: Thanks but I'm already on the latest version of pip (10.0.1) and I get "no such option: --index-url". Problem seems like it's resolved now anyway - see my own answer.